# Complex nginx rewrite rules for subdomains

Tags: nginx, subdomain, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have the following (hacky) re-write rule in my nginx.conf to allow dynamic sub-domains to be re-directed to one Django instance.

```
set $subdomain "";
set $subdomain_root "";
set $doit "";
if ($host ~* "^(.+)\.domain\.com$") {
    set $subdomain $1;
    set $subdomain_root "/profile/$subdomain";
    set $doit TR;
}
if (!-f $request_filename) {
    set $doit "${doit}UE";
}
if ($doit = TRUE) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $subdomain_root$1;
    break;
}
```

I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this but I need to change this rule so that any requests to `*.domain.com/media/*` or `*.domain.com/downloads/*` go to `domain.com/media/*` and `domain.com/downloads/*`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually I think it is much easier to change the nginx re-write rules than to write middleware for django to do this. After reading up on how nginx processes it's location matching (most exact -> least exact) I created locations for /media and /download as well as a catch all location for / I then moved the rewrite rule to under the / location and simplified it - as I'm no longer worried about checking for files because this entire location is passed to django - the rule becomes :

```
set $subdomain "";
set $subdomain_root "";
if ($host ~* "^(.+)\.domain\.com$") {
    set $subdomain $1;
    set $subdomain_root "/profile/$subdomain";
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $subdomain_root$1;
    break;
}
```

and would probably be even simpler if my nginx\regex scripting was better :)

Comment: Hello @Frozenskys I have a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744741/setting-up-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-s3-hosted-websites).I am not sure how to configure my proxy server.If possible please give your inputs.

Answer (score 9):

You can use regular expression server names (see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) and assign a matching group to a variable $subdomain directly:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443;
  server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.domain\.com$
  location / {
    rewrite ^ /profile/$subdomain$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's the best way, because using if in nginx not recommended(read more: [NGINX If Is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/))

Comment: Using if in nginx is fine as long as you understand what it does.  "Directive if has problems _when used in location context_, in some cases it doesn’t do what you expect but something completely different instead. In some cases it even segfaults." - https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better idea would be to configure django to handle subdomains instead of adding a rewrite in your webserver. Here's how I did it: http://sharjeel.2scomplement.com/2008/07/24/django-subdomains/

Comment: Hello @sharjeel I have a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744741/setting-up-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-s3-hosted-websites).I am not sure how to configure my proxy server.If possible please give your inputs